# OpenCLLink specify grid size when calling function

Tags: opencllink

The Mathematica documentation (section "Details": https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/ref/OpenCLFunction.html) states that:

> On launch, if the number of threads is not specified (as an extra
>   argument to the ), then the dimension of the element with largest rank
>   and dimension is chosen. For images, the rank is set to 2.

Great - but how do I do that when I call an OpenCL Function? There is so documentation for that..

Thanks